# Visualizing RTL control-flow graphs generated by GCC

Tags: gcc, visualization, control-flow-graph

I have got  a lot of outputs using -fdump-rtl-all flag of gcc and I was wondering how I can visualize these cfg files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found -da -dv as an alternative way to get the same output with .vcg format which is readable by graphviz.